# Flutter - When FCM push notification is clicked it's not launching app by default when app is the background

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently using FCM to push notification to my flutter app.

I try to launch the app when the user tap on a notification when the app is in background

I got this **terminal log** when I try to tap on a notification

```
    E/FirebaseMessaging(24830): Notification pending intent canceled
```

I also put this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` as the [official](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) document

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This is my **payload of the push notification**

```
    { notification: 
       { 
         title: 'title',
         body: 'body',
         badge: '1',
         icon: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/11400/1*lS9ZqdEGZrRiTcL1JUgt9w.jpeg',
         click_action: 'FlUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
         sound: 'default' 
       },
      data: { type: '4' } 
    }
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have same problem.

Comment: Removing the click_action solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

first of all your payload should be encoded as JSON :

```
     {
       'notification': {
         'body': 'this is a body',
         'title': 'this is a title'
       },
       'priority': 'high',
       'data': {
         'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
         'id': '1',
         'status': 'done'
       },
       'to': await firebaseMessaging.getToken(),
     }
```

after this try remove `'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',` from your payload and check its work or not